# Sort and filter custom post type posts by custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters, sort

I have a question as a beginner in wordpress. So for my little knowledge in coding i came to a point where i don't know the way out. I have looked through whole SE, but it seems no other thread fits my question.
My aim is:
I am on the page:

```
 http://example.com/issue/1985-02/
```

I want to list ONLY posts for the taxonomy 'issue'-slug, here '1985-02', AND sort the posts then on the page by the custom taxonomy 'productnumber' that is in the posts - in ascending order.

I got it so far that either the productnumber sorts all posts, but all slugs from 'issue' are shown (not filtered for the one slug '1985-02' as i want).
Or the specific slug of my search is filtered out - but the posts are not sorted by the productnumber of each post. This helped me:https://gist.github.com/kopepasah/3132619

Another thing: the implementation of pagination does not work.

Do you know that is my problem and please share some code that could fix it?

Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate every answer :)

---

Here's the code of taxonomy-issue.php

With this the 'productnumber' is sorted nicely, but not the issue filtered:

```
<?php
    get_header(); ?>
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
<header class="archive-header">
    <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'issue: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) ); ?></h1>
<?php // Show an optional term description.
                    $term_description = term_description();
                    if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) :
                        printf( '<div class="taxonomy-description">%s</div>', $term_description );
                    endif;
                ?>
            </header><?php
    $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'issue',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'term1' )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) {

    $term = $query->queried_object;

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        //Output what you want
           endwhile;
}

    global $post;

    $taxonomies = get_terms( 'productnumber', array( 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

        echo '<div id="' . $taxonomy->slug . '">';

            $args = array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array( $taxonomy->slug ),
                        'orderby'=> 'productnumber',
                    )
                )
            );

            query_posts( $args );

            if ( have_posts() ) : 
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                    twentyfourteen_paging_nav();
            endif;


            wp_reset_query();

        echo '</div>';

    } // end foreach

?>
</div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

And with this the 'issue' is filtered- but not sorted by productnumber:

```
<?php
    get_header(); ?>
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
<header class="archive-header">

<h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'issue: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) ); ?></h1>
<?php
                    // Show an optional term description.
                    $term_description = term_description();
                    if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) :
                        printf( '<div class="taxonomy-description">%s</div>', $term_description );
                    endif;
                ?>
            </header>


    <?php
    $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'issue',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'term1' )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) {

    $term = $query->queried_object;

    echo 'All posts found in ' . $term->name;

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        //Output what you want
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
}


    global $post;

    $taxonomies = get_terms( 'productnumber', array( 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

        echo '<div id="' . $taxonomy->slug . '">';

            $args = array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array( $taxonomy->slug ),
                        'orderby'=> 'productnumber',
                    )
                )
            );

            query_posts( $args );

            if ( have_posts() ) : 
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                    twentyfourteen_paging_nav();
            endif;


            wp_reset_query();

        echo '</div>';

    } // end foreach

?>
</div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

this is the filter in my themes function.php

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'mmx_orderby_tax_term', 10, 2 );
function mmx_orderby_tax_term( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && is_archive() && 'productnumber' == $wp_query->query['orderby'] && 'product' == $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
        $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id";
        $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)";
        $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)";
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = 'productnumber' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";
        $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
        $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    }
    return $clauses;
}
```